# is it possible to establish tcp ip between programs written in different languages

Tags: tcp

EDIT: i would really appreciate a source or an example that talks about this being done.
Some companies have a distributed program written in C++, it runs on different machines, it uses TCP/IP for inter communication between different machines (windows and linux). Is it possible to write a program from the ground up using other languages (python, java) that will be able to join their network?

Comment: Do you think all of the TCP/IP endpoints are written with the same language ?

Comment: What ever made ou think TCP/IP was langauge specific?

Comment: I have no idea, that is why i am asking this question !, and i could not find any resources that talks about this point,

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol#Communications

Answer (score 8):

Yes. Of course, TCP/IP is language agnostic. The key issue is to get the protocol correct.

Answer (score 2):

Of course! That's why it is a protocol: you don't have to know who is on the other side, as long as it follows the protocol specification

Based on edit:

This info is anywhere, based on the language you want to use. [Here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TcpCommunication) is a basic python example for tcp communication

Answer (score 2):

If you have the specification for what is being communicated (or can reverse-engineer it), then yes.  Without knowing what to send, and what to expect back it'll be a losing battle.